# Hide/show animation on one View, when happens occurs both - Android

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm creating animations to show and hide a side bar of my apk. But when the event occurs both animations get executed.

My switch anim code is

```
private boolean showingBar = true;
private void switchSideBar() {
        if (showingBar) {
            sideBar.startAnimation(hideBar);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Showing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showingBar = false;
        } else {
            showingBar = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hiding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sideBar.startAnimation(showBar);
        }
    }
```

I added those Toasts to see whats happening, and when the event occurs only one text is showed.

The code of the animations is that

showBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-50" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="300" />
```

hideBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50"
    android:duration="300" />
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do say that both animations get executed? From your toast-based analysis it seems that only one of the animations gets executed.

If you're saying that both animations get executed because the element returns to the original position when the animation ends, that's probably happening because you're not setting [`fillAfter` to `true`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3afillAfter) in your animation(s). You could also have a look into `onAnimationEnd` as an option to change your sidebar's position when opening and closing (thus making it permanent).

Comment: Really, this is what you said, the view returns to the original position, this confused. I did the onAnimationEnd approach, but I'll see now for the fillAfter. Ty!

Comment: Awesome. Enjoy your animations!